# HL7 transfer engine

Tags: hl7

I am working on a web based EMAR application which we are building in DotNet. I have a requirement to make to Pharmacy Software's with my web based EMAR. Please correct me if I am wrong, I think I need to make a transfer engine which communicate with Pharmacy Software and my web based EMAR.
This is the basic of my requirement. Now let me allow to explain what I have to achieve.

In my EMAR there are Facilities and they have Patients (Residents) there. Now If a Pharmacy of a Resident add or edit in any medication in its own software then it should automatically appear in the medication profile of web based EMAR.

I am doing some research in this from last couple of days. I found "Mirth Corp" ( http://www.mirthcorp.com/products/mirth-connect ) and "IGUANA" ( http://www.interfaceware.com/iguana.html ) which provide this. But not sure how they can help me in this.

Can anyone help me here how fulfill this requirement?

Thanks

Rahul K

Answer (score 4):

We are using [WSO2 ESB](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/) to transfer HL7 messages (ADT messages for Patient Data) from one system to the other. As it is a ESB you can transform the HL7 (file based or over TCP-IP) in any other format (XML, text) over different transports like WebService, FTP, local file or whatever. 
WSO2 is a really simple ESB and fully free & open-source. Just download and create a proxy (gets data), transform it (if you need) and send it to you application.

-- I'm not related to WSO2, so this is just my opinion ---

Of course you can use also other ESB like Mirth. Or here you can see a [list of some open-source ES](http://architects.dzone.com/news/top-open-source-esbs)B. But you need to check if they have an HL7 adapter included.

If you don't want to use any ESB, there is the Java Implementation of HL7 with the [HAPI library](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/). Then you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, i will try to go for it. will update you here.